# Maximum subarray sum such that sum is odd

Tags: php, algorithm, sum

Given an array of integers I have to find the subarray with maximum sum such that the sum is odd.

For instance in the array "2,5,7" the answer is 7,2. Till now I have come across the [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) And its implementation here http://pastebin.com/qwWzbxKw

But how do I extend it such that the sum is odd.

**EDIT**

All elements of the array are Integers and positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are not requiring it to be contiguous (from your example). This is much simpler, just take all positive elements, and if sum is odd - you are done. If it is even - remove the lowest positive odd element, or add the highest odd negative element (do which is better, it depends only on `abs(highest_negative_odd)` and `lowest_positive_odd`).

Pseudo code:

1. sum <- sum of all positive elements
2. if sum is odd - done, return the relevant subarray
3. x <- highest negative odd element
4. y <- lowest positive odd element
5. if abs(x) < y

   - sum <- sum + x //add x to the subarray
6. else:

   - sum <- sum - y //remove y from the subarray
7. return relevant subarray

**EDIT:**

For all positive number it's even easier - if the sum is not odd - just kick the smallest odd number out.

Comment: I am dealing with all positive integers here.

Comment: @Sarkar So it's even easier, just kick the smallest odd number out if the sum is not odd.